# NDK r13, -fexceptions -Wall --> warning: conflicts with previous declaration

Tags: android-ndk

After upgrading to NDK r13, the following innocent cpp file:

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

with command:
`ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 APP_CPPFLAGS=-fexceptions APP_CFLAGS=-Wall APP_STL=c++_static`

causes a warning:

```
<built-in>: In function 'float abs(float)':
<built-in>: warning: conflicts with previous declaration here [-Wattributes]
```

What has gone wrong since r12b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the 4.9 toolchain is deprecated in NDK. Switching to default toolchain (clang) resolves the issue.